# How to make a http (https) request with a lua plugin?

Tags: lua, vimscript-lua

does anyone know if it is possible to install a Lua HTTPS library that I can access from a Lua plugin in Neovim to make HTTPS requests (POST)? And how would I install such a library?

For example, to access sqlite I would just clone https://github.com/stepelu/lua-ljsqlite3.git
and https://github.com/stepelu/lua-xsys.git in my ~/example-plugin/lua/example-plugin/deps

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/writing-a-neovim-plugin-with-lua/

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is the Plugin [`rest.nvim`](https://github.com/rest-nvim/rest.nvim).

You could install it manually, which is error-prone and cumbersome. Instead I'd advice you to use the [`packer.nvim`](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim) plugin manager.

Although I suspect that using `packer.nvim` makes your goal obsolete, since it can also provides you with the ability of install luarocks libraries.

A tutorial on installing the `packer.nvim` can be found [here](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim#bootstrapping).